# Autocomplete for Python in Codemirror?

Tags: python, autocomplete, codemirror

I am trying to set up an autocomplete feature for Codemirror for the Python language. Unfortunately, it seems that Codemirror only includes the files necessary for Javascript key term completion.

Has anyone built Python hint file for CodeMirror similar to the [JavaScript Version](http://codemirror.net/lib/util/javascript-hint.js)?

(Edit for future reference: [link to similar question on CodeMirror Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/codemirror/python/codemirror/KHEb5SCuuCY/VbfMA59toAAJ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start the python autocomplete with a js based on pig-hint from codemirror 3.

You can get the `python-hint.js` [from here](http://snipt.org/zphb2).

to work, you need in your html:

1. include `simple-hint,js` and `python-hint.js`, `simple-hint.css` plus `codemirror.js`
2. add this script:

   ```
   <script>
   CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
        CodeMirror.simpleHint(cm, CodeMirror.pythonHint);
      }
   </script>
   ```

`python-hint.js` is a basic js I have created today and not reviewed in depth.

Comment: The above link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the original author of the Python parser for Codemirror (1 and 2).  You are correct that the Python parser does not offer enough information for autocomplete.  I tried to build it into the parser when Codemirror 2 came around but it proved too difficult for my JS skills at the time.

I have far more skills now but far less time.  Perhaps someday I'll get back to it.  Or if someone wants to take it up, I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Add [python-hint.js](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/72441467/), show-hint.js, show-hint.css. Then

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(your editor instance codes here;

editor.on('inputRead', function onChange(editor, input) {
    if (input.text[0] === ';' || input.text[0] === ' ' || input.text[0] === ":") {
        return;
    }
    editor.showHint({
        hint: CodeMirror.pythonHint
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
< script >
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        mode: {
            name: "python",
            version: 3,
            singleLineStringErrors: false
        },
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        extraKeys: {
            "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"
        },
        matchBrackets: true
    });
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function (cm) {
        CodeMirror.simpleHint(cm, CodeMirror.pythonHint);
    } 


 </script>
```

Comment: see below git URL for more details https://github.com/mvickymca/codemirror_python_autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize this way also, adding extraKeys parameter to CodeMirror initialization:

```
CodeMirror(function(elt) {
        myTextArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, myTextArea);
    }, {
        mode: "python",
        lineNumbers: true,
        autofocus: true,
        extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
    });
```